# Changing pvalue_thresholds, so that a new alpha (0.1 for eg instead of 0.5) can be set in Statannotations

Tags: python, statistics, seaborn, p-value

I am a biochemist and my results are too fine for my economist friends they would prefer p-value significance to be set at 10% or alpha= 0.1 instead of the standard 5% (0.05). I used Statannotations the latest v0.5. Here I have an example of what happens as a default:

```
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  import seaborn as sns
  from statannotations.Annotator import Annotator
  from statannotations import format_annotations
  
  df = sns.load_dataset('diamonds')
  df = df[df['color'].map(lambda c: c in 'EIJ')]

  x = "clarity"
  y = "carat"
  hue = "color"
  hue_order=["E", "I", "J"]
  pairs = [(("SI2", "E"), ("SI1", "E"))]
  pairs = pairs + [((clar, 'I'), (clar, 'J')) for clar in df['clarity'].unique()]
  width = 0.4

  grph = sns.catplot(kind='bar',data=df, x=x, y=y, hue=hue, hue_order=hue_order)
  for ax in grph.axes.ravel():
      annot= Annotator(ax, pairs, data=df, x=x, y=y, hue=hue, hue_order=hue_order)
      annot.configure(test='Kruskal',
                        comparisons_correction= None,
                        correction_format='replace',
                        text_format='star', 
                        line_offset=15, line_height=0.05, text_offset=1)
      annot.apply_test().annotate()

  plt.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.03, 1), title=hue)
  plt.savefig('example_barplot_hue.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
```

I want to change the alpha, which you can specify in `annot.configure` to alpha=0.1, this however throws an error telling you to change the `pvalue_thresholds` which makes sense.
I want the thresholds to be the following, which would correspond to my new alpha:

```
econ_pvalues= [[1e-3, "****"],
                [1e-2, "***"],
                [0.05, "**"],
                [0.1, "*"],
                [1, "ns"]]
```

Such that the tests are run and alternative pvalue significance levels are annotated on the graph ie: * becomes **, ** becomes *** depending on the pvalues.

I figured out how to access and change them using `format_annotations.pval_annotation_text`  ... but it makes no sense because I can only access the statstest results after I have annotated the graph and cant for the life of me find where or what more to do.

```
        annot.configure(alpha= 0.1
                        test='Kruskal',
                        comparisons_correction= None,
                        correction_format='replace',
                        text_format='star', 
                        line_offset=15, line_height=0.05, text_offset=1)
    
        annot.apply_test()
        ax, test_result= annot.annotate() #where you can access the StatResult
        
        print(test_result,'\n')
        statresults = []
        for t in test_result:
            statresults.append(t.data)
    
        econp=format_annotations.pval_annotation_text(statresults, pvalue_thresholds=econ_pvalues)
        print(econp)
```

Any help would be amazing I hope this is a comprehensive example (first time poster, python newbie)

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76938514/3896008

Comment: Yes it does, I did not find that answer you posted in my original searches - maybe because my searching was too specific. I solved it with a little help from a friend and used a similar way to go about things. Should I post my solution if this one exists already?